# Difference ls -l & ls -lsr

Tags: 16.04, ls

What is difference Between `ls -l` & `ls -lsr`
Both Are Giving Same(nearly the same) output. So what's the difference between the two commands.

Comment: Try `man ls` and see what it says.

Comment: `ls` is only one command.  You are invoking it with different options, which affect output fields and sort order.  Check the manual page for what each option does.

Comment: I can't found -lsr in manual. I have already read the manual before posting.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore sorry but ... it is there. "l" "s" and "r" as options of `man ls`

Comment: "-lsr" is not an option.  That is the same as `ls -l -s -r`; it is a shorthand convenience for specifying multiple options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `s` shows the size in blocks.
- `r` shows it in reverse order.

So this ...

> Both Are Giving Same(nearly the same) output.

I doubt is a true assessment.

---

Example:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ ls -l
total 1964
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      19 mrt 13 20:39 Desktop -> /discworld/Desktop/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      21 mrt 13 20:43 Documents -> /discworld/Documents/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      21 mrt 13 20:42 Downloads -> /discworld/Downloads/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 1966690 mei  1 21:51 Firefox_wallpaper.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind   35928 jul 29 15:06 mozilla.pdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      20 mrt 13 20:42 Pictures -> /discworld/Pictures/
drwxrwxr-x 3 rinzwind rinzwind    4096 apr 27 11:28 VirtualBox VMs
```

---

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ ls -lsr
total 1964
   4 drwxrwxr-x 3 rinzwind rinzwind    4096 apr 27 11:28 VirtualBox VMs
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      20 mrt 13 20:42 Pictures -> /discworld/Pictures/
  36 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind   35928 jul 29 15:06 mozilla.pdf
1924 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 1966690 mei  1 21:51 Firefox_wallpaper.png
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      21 mrt 13 20:42 Downloads -> /discworld/Downloads/
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      21 mrt 13 20:43 Documents -> /discworld/Documents/
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 rinzwind rinzwind      19 mrt 13 20:39 Desktop -> /discworld/Desktop/
```

---

I see 2 distinct differences here: the ordering and the 1st column.

Comment: [Rinzwind](http://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) What is the numerical value means before the file attributes? And -r sorts on which basis?

Comment: It says so in the answer: blocks. 4, 36 and 1924 blocks. The "s" option.